# Filling screen X with grid in Tkinter?

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I was wondering if any of you Tkinter experts out there could help me with a question, do any of you know if there is a alternative to packs fill=X or fill=Y commands for grids? Or some code that would add in this function?
(I have searched around for a bit and couldn't find anything)

Answer (score 11):

Use the `sticky` attribute to make objects fill the row and/or column that they are in.

Apply a weight to the rows and/or columns to get them to use any extra space in the container using [grid_rowconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_rowconfigure-method) and [grid_columnconfigure](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm#Tkinter.Grid.grid_columnconfigure-method). The "weight" defines how grid will allocate any extra space once all the children are arranged. By default, rows and columns have zero weight, meaning they don't use any extra space.

For example:

```
frame = tk.Frame(...)
l1 = tk.Label(frame, ...)
l2 = tk.Label(frame, ...)
l1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
l2.grid(row=1, column=1, stickky="nsew")
frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Comment: no idea why this information was so hard to come by. Thank you for the concise answer with all the important info included